# Oracle Date/Time manipulation query

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have problem finding a solution in oracle SQL for my query :

This is an example of the query I need :

```
Select Result_Date as hour , Type , Count(Id) as Number From Results 
Where Result_Date Between Today'06:00' And today'14:00'
group by result_date , type
```

Result date contains the hour , the format of the result date is timestamp .
How can i accomplish this query without entering the date in the between statement , only the hours between I want to search for today .

If you have any thoughts please let me know ,any idea is welcome .

Comment: the to_char function is what you want.

Comment: I've already tried the to_char and it's not comparing the strings

Comment: I've corrected the code , added today before the hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `trunc()` function on timestamps, so this might do what you want:

```
Select trunc(Result_Date, 'HH24') as hour , Type , Count(Id) as Number From Results 
Where trunc(Result_Date, 'HH24') Between '06:00' And '14:00' and
      trunc(Result_Date) = trunc(sysdate)
group by trunc(Result_Date, 'HH24'), type ;
```

Note:

`trunc()` on a date defaults to the day.  You can add the specific format for this if you like.

Comment: I also need it only for the curent day ,like  between current_day '06:00' and current_day '14:00'

Answer (score 0):

EDIT ,This is what worked for me

```
   Select to_number(extract(hour from Result_Date)) as hour , Type , Count(Id) as Number From Results Where To_Date(Trunc(Result_Date)) = To_Date(Trunc(Current_Timestamp))
        and to_number(extract(hour from Result_Date)) Between 6 and 14     
            group by  to_number(extract(hour from )Result_Date) as hour  , type
```

@Gordon Linoff , thank you dor the suggestion with trunk , it helped me allot